# Morphing Critter in GridWorld?

Tags: java, debugging, gridworld

For this new critter called AntCritter, I overwrote the processActors method and now it removes the other antcritters around it when it's supposed to change their and its color. I've tried a whole bunch of stuff but I can't figure it out because in the code it directly says not to remove the actor if it's an antcritter. The move method is basically the same as for a bug.

```
public void processActors(ArrayList<Actor> actors)
{
    for(Actor a: actors)
    {
        if(!(a instanceof AntCritter)||!(a instanceof Flower)||!(a instanceof KingCrab))
            a.removeSelfFromGrid();
        if(a instanceof AntCritter)
        {
            setColor(Color.BLUE);
            a.setColor(Color.PINK);
            ((AntCritter) a).move();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GridWorld at all, but this first condition:

```
!(a instanceof Flower)
```

will be `true` when `a` is a `AntCritter`. so the rest of the conditions in your `if` statement will never be evaluated.

Read about [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I went and fixed that, but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted in the answer about short-circuit evaluation? Now `!(a instanceof AntCritter)` will be `false` so it proceeds to `!(a instanceof Flower)` which is `true` so the statement short-circuits and removes the `AntCritter`.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot about that... Would it work to put all the separate ! statements is parenthesis? I'm going to go try that... Because with the original critter (antcritter extends critter) the statement `if(!(a instanceof Rock)|| !(a instance of Critter))` and you surround it's only next to a rock, it won't remove the rock.